# How to suffix column contents into a new column if a third column is true R

Tags: r

Hi I have a dataframe like below:

```
beverage <- c('tea', 'tea', 'coffee', 'coffee', 'tea', 'tea', 'coffee', 'coffee')
milk <- c('FALSE', 'FALSE','FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE','TRUE', 'TRUE')

df1 <- data.frame(beverage, milk)
df1
     beverage        milk
1    tea             FALSE
2    tea             FALSE
3    coffee          FALSE
4    coffee          FALSE
5    tea             TRUE
6    tea             TRUE
7    coffee          TRUE
8    coffee          TRUE
```

I would like to add another column `beverage_milk` that would take the contents of the beverage column and add `_milk` if the milk column is stated as `TRUE`. Like this:

```
     beverage        milk     beverage_milk
1    tea             FALSE    tea
2    tea             FALSE    tea
3    coffee          FALSE    coffee
4    coffee          FALSE    coffee
5    tea             TRUE     tea_milk
6    tea             TRUE     tea_milk
7    coffee          TRUE     coffee_milk
8    coffee          TRUE     coffee_milk
```

I have been thinking to use something like:

```
beverage_milk = within(beverage_milk{
beverage_milk = ifelse(milk == TRUE, beverage(+_milk), beverage})
```

obviously I know (+_milk) will not work, but this approach isn't currently working for me, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can get the solution this way:

```
library(dplyr)
beverage <- c('tea', 'tea', 'coffee', 'coffee', 'tea', 'tea', 'coffee', 'coffee')
milk <- c('FALSE', 'FALSE','FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE','TRUE', 'TRUE')
df1 <- data.frame(beverage, milk)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(beverage_milk = ifelse(milk == 'TRUE', paste0(beverage, "_milk"), paste(beverage)))

#  beverage  milk beverage_milk
#1      tea FALSE           tea
#2      tea FALSE           tea
#3   coffee FALSE        coffee
#4   coffee FALSE        coffee
#5      tea  TRUE      tea_milk
#6      tea  TRUE      tea_milk
#7   coffee  TRUE   coffee_milk
#8   coffee  TRUE   coffee_milk
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is `replace` (a bit faster then `ifelse`)

```
df1$milk <- as.logical(df1$milk)
df1$beverage_milk <- with(df1, replace(beverage, milk, paste(beverage, "milk", sep = "_")))
df1
#  beverage  milk beverage_milk
#1      tea FALSE           tea
#2      tea FALSE           tea
#3   coffee FALSE        coffee
#4   coffee FALSE        coffee
#5      tea  TRUE      tea_milk
#6      tea  TRUE      tea_milk
#7   coffee  TRUE   coffee_milk
#8   coffee  TRUE   coffee_milk
```

---

The syntax for `ifelse` could be

```
df1$beverage_milk <- with(df1, ifelse(milk, paste(beverage, "milk", sep = "_"), beverage))
```

**data**

```
beverage <- c('tea', 'tea', 'coffee', 'coffee', 'tea', 'tea', 'coffee', 'coffee')
milk <- c('FALSE', 'FALSE','FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE','TRUE', 'TRUE')

df1 <- data.frame(beverage, milk, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` option

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(beverage_milk = if_else(milk == TRUE, paste0(beverage, "_milk"), beverage))
#  beverage  milk beverage_milk
#1      tea FALSE           tea
#2      tea FALSE           tea
#3   coffee FALSE        coffee
#4   coffee FALSE        coffee
#5      tea  TRUE      tea_milk
#6      tea  TRUE      tea_milk
#7   coffee  TRUE   coffee_milk
#8   coffee  TRUE   coffee_milk
```

Or in base R

```
transform(df1, beverage_milk = ifelse(
    milk == TRUE, paste0(beverage, "_milk"), as.character(beverage)))
#  beverage  milk beverage_milk
#1      tea FALSE           tea
#2      tea FALSE           tea
#3   coffee FALSE        coffee
#4   coffee FALSE        coffee
#5      tea  TRUE      tea_milk
#6      tea  TRUE      tea_milk
#7   coffee  TRUE   coffee_milk
#8   coffee  TRUE   coffee_milk
```

PS. Your sample data is not reproducible; `beverage` contains an additional erroneous element.